# How to manipulate text to one side of a delimiter while preserving text on the opposite side

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to translate some documents in which every line is of the form:

```
name1:text to be translated 
name2:text to be translated
```

I am using [translate-shell](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell) to perform the translations. `trans -b :es -input ~/path/to/file`
The desired output would be:

```
name1:texto a traducir
name2:texto a traducir
```

But instead I am getting this output:

```
nombre1:texto a traducir
nombre2:texto a traducir
```

If I had to guess I would guess the answer probably lies in separating the fields with **awk** but I'm having difficulty understanding the man pages well enough to figure out how to do it properly. Right now I'm doing this

`awk -F: '/:/ { print $1 ": " $2 }' ~/path/to/file`

to separate the fields and then attempting to work with each field separately. But I am confused about the pattern-action statement awk. Can I run another command within the awk environment? So far all my attempts to do so have resulted in syntax errors.

Comment: Is the first part always the fiexed text "nombre", followed by digits, followed by colon? Then you could simply  "fix" the output by replacing "nombre" with "name".

Comment: No I just used name1 and name2 as examples. The actual names could be anything with letters and/or numbers and/or underscores. But the name is always followed by a colon.

Comment: Can there be `:`s in `text to be translated`? Can there be newlines? Edit your question to include EXAMPLEs of the hard cases, not just `name1:text` as that tells us nothing about what names and text might contain. Can/should `trans` be called on individual strings (and if so what does that syntax look like) or must/should it be on a whole file?

Comment: @EdMorton Would it be sufficient if I provide the regex I use to obtain the lines of text? It would not be ethical in this case to provide actual real life examples.

Comment: No and no-one's asking you to provide real life examples, just examples that follow the same style/format as your worst-case real life examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a recipe involving `cut` and `paste`:

1. cut the names and texts into two separated files:

   ```
   cut -d: -f1 yourfile > names.txt
   cut -d: -f2- yourfile > text.txt
   ```
2. translate `text.txt` using whatever workflow you are using at the moment
3. combine the old names.txt with the translated text:

   ```
   paste -d: names.txt yourtranslated_text
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I think @LarsFischer has the best answer so far but just in case you have some reason to need to use awk and you can pass individual strings to "trans" and the text to be translated cannot contain newlines, this is how you'd do it:

```
awk '
{
    name = text = $0
    sub(/:.*/,"",name)
    sub(/[^:]+:/,"",text)
    cmd = "trans args \"" text "\""
    if ( (cmd | getline rslt) > 0 ) {
        print name ":" rslt
    }
    close(cmd)
}
' file
```

Comment: I know this was asked a long time ago but I keep coming back to this awk code as it is quite useful. If need be I can ask a new question but I was just wondering if there is a simple way of combining the code above with `awk '!seen[$0]++ { print; fflush() }'`?

Comment: Post a new question as your requirements aren't clear from that comment.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't get the translate-shell to work but maybe something like this:

```
awk -v dq='"' -F: '{printf "%s ", $1; gsub(/^.*:/,""); system("trans -b :es "dq""$0""dq)}' test.in
```

Comment: I wouldn't assume there's no `:`s in `text to be translated`, nor would I assume that the system() output will occur exactly in step with the `printf`s.

Comment: Indeed there are sometimes colons in the text to be translated portion of the line. `name3:text to be translated :)`

Comment: Fair enough. Dealt with the colon issue. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

another alternative is paste the original and translated files together and cut the needed fields, that is

```
paste -d: original translation | cut -d: -f1,4
```

Comment: That will fail given `:`s in the text to translate.

Comment: and apparently it can happen, see the OPs comment under http://stackoverflow.com/a/38421524/1745001